# Open password protected workbook using visual basic

Tags: vba

I need to open and get some information from a password protected workbook. The dialog box says "the workbook is protected by bla bla". One can then write the password, choose read-only or cancel and if password is inserted one can also choose ok.

Is there a way for me, when opening the workbook using visual basic commands, to automatically choose "Read only" in that dialog box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Object Browser (F2) says,

```
Function Open(Filename As String, [UpdateLinks], [ReadOnly], [Format], [Password], [WriteResPassword], [IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended], [Origin], [Delimiter], [Editable], [Notify], [Converter], [AddToMru], [Local], [CorruptLoad]) As Workbook
    Member of Excel.Workbooks
```